# HikariCP: SELECT queries execute roll back due to dirty commit state on close()

Tags: jdbc, hikaricp

I am trying to use HikarCP in a legacy system. I configured autocommit to false, which is what we want, and realized that my logs are filled with

```
[c.z.h.p.ProxyConnection][ProxyConnection.java:232] ora - Executed rollback on connection net.sf.log4jdbc.ConnectionSpy@3f2bba67 due to dirty commit state on close().
```

This is happening when a connection acquired from the pool is closed after issuing a finder query. No insert/update/delete's are happening within the life of connection. Is this how it should be for select queries? Should I be doing a COMMIT after each select?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you should be committing.  Even SELECT queries initiate transactions and acquire locks.  Particularly with various isolation levels, and depending on the database even with TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED.

HikariCP treats a non-explicit commit when autocommit is *false* as an application error.  Some other pools support configuring "commit-on-close", but HikariCP considers that risky, and a hack to support applications that were never properly written.

The JDBC specification is explicitly silent on whether a Connection without auto commit should automatically commit or rollback.  That is an implementation detail left up the the driver developers.

Comment: I prefer an explicit `commit()` myself.  In my recent case; I have finished the transaction and called `commit()`.  Yet, I still see this message in my logfile.

Comment: I use Hikari in spring boot, letting spring handle the trx via its @Transactional annotation. I see this message from Hikari (issued at DEBUG level) at the end of some transactions, where read-only is set to true (as a property of the annotation). I also see it issued when a 3rd party library (JobRunr) uses read-only transactions. I think I cannot do anything against it aside from using auto-commit, that I definitely don't want to.